# php regular comment remove

Tags: php, expression, comments

how remove multi line comment ? ( `/* comment php */`) from file .php
how remove single comment ? ( `// coment` ) from file.php
how remove enter end line ?
sample :
single comment line

```
$G["url"] = "http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]

multi comment line

      /*
         * 310 
         * - "::"
         * - $col
         */
```

Comment: `HTTP_HOST` [is evil](http://perfect-co.de/2011/02/why-http_host-is-evil/).

Comment: @Linus false alarms are evil. The above example actually only works for the default virtual host

Comment: @Shrapnel I know. It's my post. I must have missed it in the OP, though. Where does it say the code runs not on the default vhost?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the code posted below, it even ignores comment tokens on strings like " /* comment2 */ "

```
<?php

$fileIn = "src.php"; 
$fileOut = "srcCompressed.php"; 

$text = file_get_contents($fileIn);

$text = compress_php_src($text);

file_put_contents($fileOut, $text);


function compress_php_src($src) {
    // Whitespaces left and right from this signs can be ignored
    static $IW = array(
        T_CONCAT_EQUAL,             // .=
        T_DOUBLE_ARROW,             // =>
        T_BOOLEAN_AND,              // &&
        T_BOOLEAN_OR,               // ||
        T_IS_EQUAL,                 // ==
        T_IS_NOT_EQUAL,             // != or <>
        T_IS_SMALLER_OR_EQUAL,      // <=
        T_IS_GREATER_OR_EQUAL,      // >=
        T_INC,                      // ++
        T_DEC,                      // --
        T_PLUS_EQUAL,               // +=
        T_MINUS_EQUAL,              // -=
        T_MUL_EQUAL,                // *=
        T_DIV_EQUAL,                // /=
        T_IS_IDENTICAL,             // ===
        T_IS_NOT_IDENTICAL,         // !==
        T_DOUBLE_COLON,             // ::
        T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM,     // ::
        T_OBJECT_OPERATOR,          // ->
        T_DOLLAR_OPEN_CURLY_BRACES, // ${
        T_AND_EQUAL,                // &=
        T_MOD_EQUAL,                // %=
        T_XOR_EQUAL,                // ^=
        T_OR_EQUAL,                 // |=
        T_SL,                       // <<
        T_SR,                       // >>
        T_SL_EQUAL,                 // <<=
        T_SR_EQUAL,                 // >>=
    );
    if(is_file($src)) {
        if(!$src = file_get_contents($src)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    $tokens = token_get_all($src);

    $new = "";
    $c = sizeof($tokens);
    $iw = false; // ignore whitespace
    $ih = false; // in HEREDOC
    $ls = "";    // last sign
    $ot = null;  // open tag
    for($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
        $token = $tokens[$i];
        if(is_array($token)) {
            list($tn, $ts) = $token; // tokens: number, string, line
            $tname = token_name($tn);
            if($tn == T_INLINE_HTML) {
                $new .= $ts;
                $iw = false;
            } else {
                if($tn == T_OPEN_TAG) {
                    if(strpos($ts, " ") || strpos($ts, "\n") || strpos($ts, "\t") || strpos($ts, "\r")) {
                        $ts = rtrim($ts);
                    }
                    $ts .= " ";
                    $new .= $ts;
                    $ot = T_OPEN_TAG;
                    $iw = true;
                } elseif($tn == T_OPEN_TAG_WITH_ECHO) {
                    $new .= $ts;
                    $ot = T_OPEN_TAG_WITH_ECHO;
                    $iw = true;
                } elseif($tn == T_CLOSE_TAG) {
                    if($ot == T_OPEN_TAG_WITH_ECHO) {
                        $new = rtrim($new, "; ");
                    } else {
                        $ts = " ".$ts;
                    }
                    $new .= $ts;
                    $ot = null;
                    $iw = false;
                } elseif(in_array($tn, $IW)) {
                    $new .= $ts;
                    $iw = true;
                } elseif($tn == T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING
                       || $tn == T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE)
                {
                    if($ts[0] == '"') {
                        $ts = addcslashes($ts, "\n\t\r");
                    }
                    $new .= $ts;
                    $iw = true;
                } elseif($tn == T_WHITESPACE) {
                    $nt = @$tokens[$i+1];
                    if(!$iw && (!is_string($nt) || $nt == '$') && !in_array($nt[0], $IW)) {
                        $new .= " ";
                    }
                    $iw = false;
                } elseif($tn == T_START_HEREDOC) {
                    $new .= "<<<S\n";
                    $iw = false;
                    $ih = true; // in HEREDOC
                } elseif($tn == T_END_HEREDOC) {
                    $new .= "S;";
                    $iw = true;
                    $ih = false; // in HEREDOC
                    for($j = $i+1; $j < $c; $j++) {
                        if(is_string($tokens[$j]) && $tokens[$j] == ";") {
                            $i = $j;
                            break;
                        } else if($tokens[$j][0] == T_CLOSE_TAG) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                } elseif($tn == T_COMMENT || $tn == T_DOC_COMMENT) {
                    $iw = true;
                } else {
                    if(!$ih) {
                        $ts = strtolower($ts);
                    }
                    $new .= $ts;
                    $iw = false;
                }
            }
            $ls = "";
        } else {
            if(($token != ";" && $token != ":") || $ls != $token) {
                $new .= $token;
                $ls = $token;
            }
            $iw = true;
        }
    }
    return $new;
}
?>
```

Credits to gelamu function [compress_php_src()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-strip-whitespace.php#82437).

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to remove comments from your code. The overhead from processing them is so incredibly minimal that it doesn't justify the effort.

Comment: @saeed there's no reason to commpress php file as well

Answer (score 1):

I think you are probably looking for [php_strip_whitespace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-strip-whitespace.php).

Comment: @saeed Damaged in what way? Also, look down the comments on the manual page linked above and you will find many alternative solutions using the [Tokenizer extension](http://uk2.php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php).